# concurrency issue when fetching unread emails from more than one window processes

Tags: c#, windows, service

I want to fetch emails from an exchange server via more than one windows service; each windows service on separate servers. I am leaning towards using third party tools to fetch emails.

I am concerned about concurrency issues; ie: two services grabbing the same email at the same moment. I DO NOT want to use a controller process that will control which process gets which email.

I am thinking of a locking mechanism, similar to database locks, that each process can lock the email while in process and then mark it, once done. OR

A 'fetch' method that will mark the email instantaneously. in micro micro seconds or even less before any other process gets to it. OR

Any other idea that comes to mind.

Much Obliged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to use DB with locking some table. Have your service to populate the table with ToDos and then mark them as completed. Your services will need to point to one place where they will get a work Todo, so this is going to be your concurrency solution. May be, one service just to populate TODOs and others to process them. May be MSMQ can help. One service stacking the queue, others un-stocking.

Comment: Regarding the concurrency issue. Is using webdav a workable solution?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

here is something that you may want to look at 
[.NET POP3 MIME Client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21377/NET-POP3-MIME-Client)

you may want to try something like this in code as an example as well

```
    Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("Mapi");
    object _missing = Type.Missing;
    ns.Logon(_missing, _missing, false, true);
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    int unread = inbox.UnReadItemCount;
    foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in inbox.Items)
    {
        string s = mail.Subject;
    }
```

Comment: Regarding the concurrency issue. Is using webdav a workable solution?